# IP address is shown instead of the actuall website address in the browser address bar

Tags: apache

I didn't know what words to pick to create a title proper to my problem, so please don't get angry to me. My problem is about configuring VirtualHost of my websites. I have managed partially.

I have defined the virtual host like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/magento

    ServerName name.website.com
    ServerAlias name.website.com

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

I am a little bit new to this server administration stuff. What I want is that when I enter the `name.website.com` to the address bar, user should see my website which located in magento direction above. I have wrote the apache configuration above with that purpose in mind.

I have partially succeeded, which means, when I enter the `name.website.com` to the address bar, I can see my website. But in the address bar I can't see my website address which is `name.website.com`, but instead, I see my server's IP addres and the folder in which my site resides.(Eg. `111.111.111.111/magento`). I would like my website address to be shown, not the IP address.

What am I missing? Apache 2.4.7, Ubuntu 16.04, PHP 5.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this has anything to do with Apache itself. I think this has something to do with Magento instead.

Did you try changing the base URL in Magento as this article explains? https://docs.nexcess.net/article/how-to-change-magento-base-urls.html

Comment: Yeah. I have checket with an another website. I think you are right.